# Exclude subfolder from WP-redirect works with html but not php files

Tags: htaccess, directory, exclude

I want a certain subfolder excluded from being handled by WP with its 404 - page not found message.

My problem is:

- `example.com/Non_WP/myfile.html` - **shows correctly**

*but*

- `example.com/Non_WP/myfile.php` - will trigger a **WP 404-page not found** message.

Both files, `myfile.html` and `myfile.php` exist in the `Non_WP` folder.

My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(Non_WP|Non_WP/.*)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

It *should* exclude WP from handling the "Non_WP" folder.

WP is installed in the root folder and there are no redirect-plugins active.

**Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Any idea where to locate the problem other than the `.htaccess` file?**

Answer (score 1):

Well localized the problem (without understanding it so far)

It was **not the .htaccess file**.

It was **not plugins or themes** (which I deactivated all to see what happens)

But my little php app had their own **session handling** and modified **the header**. Just simple textbook stuff (login etc..) which works flawless outside WP.

I didn't analyse why this happens, but without the session/header stuff my php app works fine alongside WP.

Comment: I found the cause as well. My login page in the Non-WP folder destroyed the session first. That was to avoid multiple logins.

Seems like this messed with WP. With that line gone everything worked well.

Answer (score 0):

There's "something else" going on. Providing these two files exist (as you say they do) then you shouldn't have to do anything to allow direct access. This is what the two `RewriteCond` directives do that check against `REQUEST_FILENAME` - these two conditions ensure that only requests that do not map to existing files/directories are routed through WP. Without these two conditions then none of your static resources (CSS, JS, images, etc.) would work.

Your additional condition to exclude the `/Non_WP` directory is an optimisation, since it prevents the file/directory checks. However, as mentioned above, this should not be necessary to make it "work".

However, this "optimisation" should be moved outside of the `# BEGIN WordPress` block, to prevent your modification being overwritten by WordPress later. Instead of modifying the WordPress block, include the following directive *before* the WordPress directives (before the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment):

```
RewriteRule ^(Non_WP|Non_WP/.*)$ - [L]
```

This is effectively the reverse of your *condition*. If the `/Non_WP` directory is accessed then do nothing. No further processing of the mod_rewrite directives in the `.htaccess` file will occur.

Comment: Well, it didn't resolve my problem.
Thanx for your hints about #Begin WordPress.

Comment: Do you have any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories? Do you have access to the server config, in which directives might have been placed?